# Ways to find records based on their first letter awk Unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I would like to take out only persons with name starting with A using awk. How do i do it

```
REGNO   NAME            DEPT            AVG             STATUS
100     Tony            ECE             30              FAIL
200     Jimmy           ECE             67              PASS
300     Sanjay          CSE             89              PASS
400     Nethra          IT              90              PASS
500     Ramesh          MECH            45              FAIL
600     Ranjani         CSE             34              FAIL
700     Aarthi          IT              56              PASS
800     Ram             MECH            98              PASS
```

```
awk '{if($2=="A*" && $3=="IT" )  print $2,$3}' output.txt
```

I used this. What is wrong?

Comment: `awk '$2~/^A/ && $3=="IT"{print $2,$3}' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '$2 ~ "^A" && $3 == "IT" {print $2, $3}'
```

There is no wildcard matching like `== "A*"`

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you:

```
kent$  awk '$2~/^A/&&$3=="IT"{print $2,$3}' file
Aarthi IT
```

Your problem is, confused by glob and regex.

In awk, `==` won't do glob check, it compares two values, check if they are equal. `~` is a regex matching check, it expect a static or dynamic regex expression.

Comment: Correct. The OP will probably want to thrown in `NR>1` too so if/when looking for names that start with `N` it doesn't match the header line, esp if/when they aren't adding a second condition on a different field value: `awk '(NR>1) && ($2~/^A/) && ($3=="IT") {print $2, $3}' file`.